# How to detect AWS EC2 architecture from inside?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-architecture

Assuming we have instance running, what can we run on that instance to detect whether it's `x86_64` or graviton-based/ARM?

I thought about `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/...` but found nothing useful in this case. Also, it's possible to detect using instance type (e.g. `t4g.*` vs `t3.*`) but I'd like to have more straightforward way.

Is there any?

Comment: Could you parse `uname` to determine the architecture? Eg could you treat this question as if it has nothing to do with AWS?

Comment: @jaredready in theory, yes. Just want to make sure it's really reliable way _in AWS_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Quick and easy check: `uname -m`

Intel / AMD:

```
t3a.large:~ $ uname -m
x86_64
```

Graviton / ARM:

```
t4g.large:~ $ uname -m
aarch64
```

#### Display more details: `lscpu`

For example for AMD CPU:

```
t3a.large:~ $ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              1
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model name:                      AMD EPYC 7571
CPU MHz:                         2199.880
BogoMIPS:                        4399.76
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       32 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
...
```

You can also display the output in JSON format for easier consumption in scripts (here for Graviton):

```
t4g.large:~ $ lscpu -J
{
   "lscpu": [
      {"field":"Architecture:", "data":"aarch64"},
      {"field":"CPU op-mode(s):", "data":"32-bit, 64-bit"},
      {"field":"Byte Order:", "data":"Little Endian"},
      {"field":"CPU(s):", "data":"2"},
      {"field":"On-line CPU(s) list:", "data":"0,1"},
      {"field":"Thread(s) per core:", "data":"1"},
      {"field":"Core(s) per socket:", "data":"2"},
      {"field":"Vendor ID:", "data":"ARM"},
      {"field":"Model name:", "data":"Neoverse-N1"},
      ...
   ]
}
```

Hope that helps :)